# MAAS installation failing at database migrations (Rendering model states)

Tags: maas

I'm trying to install MAAS on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) per instructions at https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/installconfig-package-install. I am running it as a Vagrant box using image `ubuntu/xenial64`. I've added the `ppa:maas/next` (I've also tried with `ppa:maas/stable` for 2.1 and it fails in the same way) repository and then while installing with `sudo apt install maas` it fails:

```
Setting up maas-region-controller (2.2.0+bzr6054-0ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/maas-region-controller.conf

Creating config file /etc/dbconfig-common/maas-region-controller.conf with new version
creating postgres user maas:  success.
verifying creation of user: success.
creating database maasdb: success.
verifying database maasdb exists: success.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: piston3, maasserver, contenttypes, sessions, sites, auth, metadataserver
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...dpkg: error processing package maas-region-controller (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 247
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas:
 maas depends on maas-region-controller (= 2.2.0+bzr6054-0ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package maas-region-controller is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package maas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 maas-region-controller
 maas
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tracked it down to the migration command which has a more verbose option but doesn't seem to give any more output:

```
ubuntu@maas:~$ sudo maas-region dbupgrade -v 3
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, sites, contenttypes, piston3, maasserver, metadataserver
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...ubuntu@maas:~$ echo $?
247
```

I can't find any relevant logs in `/var/log/maas`, `/var/log/apt`, or `/var/log/dpkg.log`. But I can post them if you think they would be helpful. I am not quite sure how to further debug the `dbupgrade` command.

What am I doing wrong that isn't allowing me to install MAAS?

Comment: Just ran into this myself.  This is why I often hate using open source products. Instead of ranting, I'll ask if you ever got past this?

Comment: Nope. I tried 1.x a long while ago and also had no luck ever getting it running. It makes me wonder... who is actually running this in the data center? I love the feature list and the idea of it. But it definitely seems architecturally complex and hard to believe it would be production ready if it can't even be installed using the guide.

Comment: the problem is in the Postgres installer, and it appears to be a frequent regression in the ubuntu stack.  People who are running it install the baseline server, then postgres, then the MAAS layers.

Comment: Do you have specific package names for the order? I'm happy to try it. Just not sure what "baseline server" and "MAAS layers" are.

Comment: I used the Ubuntu Server 17.04 LTS distribution. I installed the basic server with postgres and ssh only.  Then I installed maas-region-controller and maas-rack-controller, then after that any other packages you need. This sidesteps the problem with the postgres installer in the maas bootstrap installation.

Comment: Ah, OK I see, it sounds like maybe the meta `maas` package is trying to install a different version of postgres that conflicts with something in the installer.